# Having 2 compiling errors in my java program . clarification please

Tags: java, constructor

The errors I am getting are 
1 a cannot find symbol error

and

2 "constructor circle, in class circle cannot be applied to given types. "

At this point I just can seem to grasp what I did wrong.

```
 public class Circle {
     private double radius;

     public Circle (double radius) {
         radius = radius;
     }      

     public double getRadius() {
         return radius;
     }

     public double getArea() {
         return radius * radius * Math.PI;
     }
}

class B extends Circle {
    private double length;

    B (double radius, double length) {
        Circle (radius);
        length = length;
    }

    //**override getArea()*/
    public double getArea() { 
        return getArea() * length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since no methods set the radius and length, declare the instance variables to be `final`. It makes the intent clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to change:

```
radius = radius;
```

to

```
this.radius = radius; // 'this' makes reference to the actual instance
```

And change the `B` constructor to:

```
public Test(double radius, double length)
{
    super(radius); // Calls super class constructor
    this.length = length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At super-class `Circle` use `this` to refer current instance.

```
 public Circle (double radius) {
     this.radius = radius;// Use this
 }
```

At sub-class use `super()` to access super-class constructor. Change from

```
B (double radius, double length) {
Circle (radius);// This is compilation error.
length = length;
}
```

To

```
B (double radius, double length) {
super(radius); // This is the way to access super-clss constructor.
this.length = length; //Use this to refer current instance length.
}
```

Comment: And use `this.length = length` in the constructor too.  Otherwise, `length` is interpreted as the argument, not the instance variable, and the instance variable is never set.  Actually, use `final double length` in the constructor argument list. You might also want to restrict `radius` to be positive.

Comment: ah I see thanks. ( I got another error telling me I need to define the main class as  public static void main (string[]args)     )

Comment: That should be `public static void main (String[] args)` to run code.